# jQuery validator not working for file input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to implemenet validation for file input type using jQuery validator plugin.
The file input type should accept only images with .jpeg, .jpg & .png extension & file size should not be greater than 1MB.
Validation for other input fields work without any issues. Required validation works for file input type.

What could be the issue?

Javascript

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
   return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param) 
});    

$('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 6,
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                minlength: 6,
                required: true
            },
            file: {
                required: true, 
                accept: "png|jpeg|jpg",
                filesize: 1048576 
            }
        },
        messages: 
           { 
            file: "File must be JPEG or PNG, less than 1MB" 
           },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control"  name="firstname" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="lastname" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="file">Image:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input  id="file" name="file" type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Fiddle that doesn't give desired result](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/mv8w3m0c/)

Comment: I get a call error in the console

Comment: *"...should accept only images with .jpeg, .jpg & .png extension"* ~ [The `accept` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/) is only for MIME types.  [The `extension` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/) is for file extensions.  You also need to include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) for these rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...should accept only images with .jpeg, .jpg & .png extension

1. [The `accept` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/) is only for MIME types.  [The `extension` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/) is for file extensions.    Looks like you should be using the `extension` rule instead of `accept`.  You also need to include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) in order to use these rules.
2. In order to have access to the file's size property, you need to set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on the `<form>` tag.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/mv8w3m0c/1/**